# Javascript closure property manipulation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

There's a few threads on here that address this but none that gave a clear and concise answer to my problem.

If I have a function such as the following;

```
function test(){
    var abc = "some value";

    return function concat(str) {
        return str + " " + abc;
    }
}
```

such that i can concatenate a string with the "some value" string contained in the closure as follows

```
var myStr = test()
console.log(myStr("this is"))
```

is there some way I can manipulate the abc variable at the point of defining myStr?

I've been working with d3 quite a bit recently and building scales works as follows;

```
var myScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(...)
    .range(...)
```

which I'm guessing works behind the scenes in a similar way to what I want to achieve.

EDIT: This is what I wanted to achieve;

```
function test(){
    var abc = "some value";

    function concat(str) {
        return str + " " + abc;
    }
    concat.abc = function(value) {
        if (!arguments.length) { return abc;}
        abc = value;
        return concat;
    }
    return concat;
}

var myStr = test()
    .abc("another test")

console.log(myStr("this is"))
```

Not sure I completely follow what's happening.

Is concat.abc referencing the abc property within concat? Why are we returning concat from within the concat.abc property definition?

Comment: "is there some way I can manipulate the abc variable at the point of defining myStr?" - lots. What, precisely, do you want to achieve? It's not much help being specific about what you can do and vague about what you want to do.

Comment: Are you talking about passing in a variable into `test` when you define `myStr`, or are you talking about chaining methods? Or both?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I'm trying to better understand js and learn programming best practices, ultimately. I bought a book called Mastering D3.js and the second chapter aims to teach the reader how to create Reusable Charts. The emphasis here is on encapsulating creation of elements into reusable code blocks. The examples make use of Accessor methods to configure variables inside the closure and I was struggling to replicate the functionality in my own examples. I've got it working now, though, and have updated the Q.

Comment: @hwilson1 sounds like a painful way to learn JavaScript

Comment: @JustinY there's an alternative way?

Comment: @hwilson1 Well d3 is almost like another language. I would start with just JS.

Comment: @JustinY I already know quite a bit of both d3 and js. The problem with most js literature is they talk you through variables, functions, objects, and usually put the focus on interacting with the DOM and input elements specifically (validating input, checking and acting on input values etc). You think you know it all, then you go ahead and see 50 types of function / ways of utilising functions and objects that you would just never have naturally arrived at with just that basic layer of understanding delivered in most literature. If you know any good intermediate-advance books do let me know!

Comment: Learn JS first, maybe you think you know a lot about it, but based on your question you don't. If you can't figure out which books would be good starting points after 5 mins of googling then there is a more fundamental problem...

Comment: I really don't think I know a lot about it, I've barely scratched the surface and certainly have very little working understanding of js. I have passed the Microsoft HTML, CSS and js exam though so, point being im not a complete newbie. I don't remeber covering off functions nested within functions however, hence my question on here.

Comment: The point is you clearly don't have the prerequisite JS knowledge required by the d3 book you are using - unless you just want to learn it by rote without understanding it, and clearly this is not the case.  Hence my advice is for you to take a step back and get the fundamentals of JS under your belt first.

Comment: And that's good advice which I'll take. I've ordered "Object-Oriented JavaScript" by Stoyan Stefanov, if there's better books out there that go deep into objects/functions then I'd be happy to hear about them. Most of the books I've so far looked at are html/css/js hybrids and as I mentioned before, would explain core js functionality without offering much depth, certainly not covering 'functions within functions'.

Comment: My learning curve is still very steep so I can give a fresh perspective perhaps, I found that you need to read several books to get a feel for things and it's easy to find them with a bit of google foo... the one you mention is one of the "must reads".  My experience is that, if C# is rigorous like classical music, that JS is expressive like Jazz.  I know that sounds a bit strange, but that's how it feels to me.  C# is very opinionated so you learn the rules and are forced by the syntax to follow them.  JS is much more open and it feels like your improvising instinctively, so...

Comment: ...you need to get a "feel" for it.  That's why I recommend reading several books about it then practice quite a bit.  And keep referring back to the patterns presented in the books to test and analyse your improvisations to develop your feel.  Unfortunately, that's the way it seems to go with JS; the learning experience is far from linear.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This book is phenomenal so far. Will polish this off and then as you say, practice, practice, practice.

Answer (score 0):

you can create classes in javascript and then create setter and getter for the values inside of the closure.
Here is an example:

```js
function test() {

  var abc = "default value";

  this.setAbc = function(text) {
    abc = text;
    return this;
  }

  this._concat=function(str) {
    return str + " " + abc;
  }
}

var myStr = new test();

document.write(myStr.setAbc("new value")._concat("this is"))
```